# Severe Graphical glitches after updating Ubuntu's packages using the Software Updater

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, amd-graphics, lts

Specs:

- Intel i5-2400 3.4ghz
- Dell AMD Radeon R7 250 2gb VRAM
- 16gb of ram ddr3
- 1TB of space, HDD

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

So i've decided to update my system's packages after every week with the software updater and after it finished updating i've tried to play a game using wine that uses the vulkan drivers and boom, the system froze and i thought that it was a simple lag spike and that it would pass away quickly, but to my surprise and after rebooting, i got a super strange graphical glitch that hasn't happened to me before, it looks like a TV's static noise and the mouse pointer has a glitched square too, everything looked frozen for a minute then the "TV Static" started moving, i can't use the system and i've just booted into my Ubuntu 20.04 USB just right and backed up some things after chrooting into my disk just in case that i have to re install everything from zero.

I appreciate any attempts to fix my system or help me, thanks for your attention.

EXTRA: I've also researched about amd drivers failing in ubuntu and i've checked them, if it helps i have the radeon driver and the amdgpu one, i don't know if i'm supposed to have one of them or both.
I can also try to send a photo of the glitch if it's necessary too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i've finally deciphered what was happening, my computer had the last amd gpu graphics that were unstable from ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers, i've installed ppa-purge in my ubuntu system on which i've chrooted using the usb and then proceeded to use it on that PPA i've mentioned, it reverted everything i've installed in that ppa and deleted some packages, i've also deleted packages that weren't needed just in case with apt autoremove, [this page gave me the idea](https://linuxconfig.org/amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation) and right after I saw the words "revert" and "packages", I knew that I was probably in a good path.

After unmounting and etc, I rebooted thinking that it wasn't gonna work but to  my surprise everything booted as it should and there wasn't any TV static graphical glitches anymore.

---

Moral:
**Do not install experimental/unstable drivers, otherwhise things may happen one day and if you don't have an USB or CD, you're gonna regret it.**